# Is the number the power of 2 - without using log10 ? PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to **PHP**
I was taking coding challenge and I stumbled on this
piece of code :

```
// check whether a given positive integer is a power of two.
```

The solution

```
function is_Power_of_two($n)
{
   if(($n & ($n - 1)) == 0)
    {
        return "$n is power of 2";
    }
   else
    {
        return "$n is not power of 2";
    }
}
print_r(is_Power_of_two(4)."\n");
print_r(is_Power_of_two(128)."\n");
print_r(is_Power_of_two(16)."\n");
```

In the `if` section, what is happening there ?

let's say $n = 2

```
2 & 2 - 1 == 0 // replaced $n with num
2 & 1 == 0 ? // results , What ?
```

EDIT :

So basicly

`&` isn't a **logical operator**

It is a [bitwise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php#language.operators.bitwise) Operator

> Bitwise operators allow evaluation and manipulation of specific bits
> within an integer.

You can check this video that I found very helpful it will show you how bit's work and how you can work with bitwise

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U-bh4gSn1k

And thanks to : [kollol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8940776/kollol)

now I get why the solution code return only the power of two values

Also thanks to :
[lars-stegelitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2443226/lars-stegelitz)
[kiko-software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software)

Comment: What is the question? Operators are explained here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: how dose `2 and 1 == 0` make it return in the power of 2 line

Comment: Because it is a [bitwise AND](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: `&` is binary-AND, not logical-AND `&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if both digits are same vertically then the value will be 1, 0 otherwise
for example

```
2 & 16 = (binary of 2) & (binary of 16)
          00010    &      10000
       =  00000 = 0

    (2)  00010
    (16) 10000
------------------
         00000
```

now suppose

```
2 & 18 = (binary of 2) & (binary of 18)
          00010    &      10010
   
   (2)  00010
   (18) 10010
----------------------
        00010  = not 0
```

logic is all the numbers which are power of two will always get a `0` in `bitwise and operation` with `2`. Rest will not .